# Laravel Relationship Search

Tags: laravel, orm, model, laravel-8

I'm building a project with Laravel 8. I need to handle request parameter which contains page, limit, searchColumn, searchText, orderColumn and orderDirection. Sometimes I need to search in relations. I've built this system below but it doesn't work on relationships.

```
        $query = (new Log())->newQuery();
        $query->with('customer', 'domain', 'type');

        if ($request->searchColumn != "" && $request->searchColumn != NULL) {
            $query->where($request->searchColumn, 'LIKE', '%' . $request->searchText . '%');
        }

        if ($request->orderColumn != "" && $request->orderColumn != NULL) {
            $query->orderBy($request->orderColumn, $request->orderDirection);;
        }

        $logs = $query->paginate($request->limit, ['*'], '', $request->page);
```

For example if `$request->searchColumn` is 'customer.name', how should I search? I've tried few ways but they don't work.

Comment: Would constraint eager loading help? It adds a constraint on the relationship model.
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

Comment: Should I remove 'with' at second line?

Answer (score 0):

You may use `whereHas` method which allow to define additional query constraints on your relation. E.g:

```php
$searchText = $request->searchText;
if ( explode( '.', $request->searchColumn )[0] == 'customer' ) {
    $query->whereHas( 'customer', function( $query ) use ( $searchText ) {
         $query->where( 'name', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchText . '%' )
    });
}
```

Comment: Should I remove 'with' in the second line?